# Is it possible to customise the Cordova CLI directory structure?

Tags: java, angularjs, cordova, maven

I'm trying to wrap an existing Java web app as a mobile app using Cordova. The client side code is a single-page app built in Angular and the project is being built with Maven.

Is it possible to modify the default Cordova project structure to say, point `www` to `src/main/webapp` instead? Has anyone successfully integrated Cordova into a standard Maven web app directory structure? It would be great to avoid having to maintain a separate mobile and web code base.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't alter the www/ folder, but you could try one of these approaches: use a hook (before_prepare) or some kind of build process (gulp) to copy over src/main/webapp to the www/ folder, or modify config.xml to load the default page from that folder (`<content src="src/main/webapp/index.html" />`)

Comment: That's not a bad idea, thanks I'll see how that goes. Shame that you can't change it though. Seems like convention over configuration taken to extremes.